# The real function $f$ such that $\log \cdots \log (f)$ is strictly convex on its domain for any number of $\log$'s

Tags: real-analysis, functions, logarithms, convex-analysis, iterated-function-system

Does there exist a function $f: (a,b) \to \mathbb R$ ($a,b$ are allowed to be infinity) such that $\log \cdots \log (f)$ is strictly convex *on its whole domain of definition* for an arbitrary number (though finitely many) of $\log$'s?

If such function exists, it must be very very convex ("more convex" than any $\exp \dots \exp (x) $, which will become concave after a finitely many $\log$'s applied on)

The form of $f$ doesn't have to be concrete. It can be infinite series or one can even show its existence or nonexistence.

Comment: Does this make sense, actually? After some number of $\log$s, wouldn't you get something to which you cannot apply $\log$?

Comment: @Fimpellizieri that is why I say "on its domain".  Note that loglog...logloglog(x) is always defined for large x.

Comment: Try with something stronger, like $f(x)=\Gamma(x)$

Comment: @Raffaele Unfortunately the software plotting gives me a negative answer. $ \log \log(\Gamma(x))$ is concave somewhere...

Comment: that the Gamma function does not work is obvious from Stirling's approximation

Comment: I was thinking about $f(x) = \exp(f(x-1))$ but cannot create a complete example

Comment: @LinAlg I think this is a great idea. First show that a function satisfying a certain function equation has the given property and then show that such function equation has a solution...

Comment: @NoOne  Raffaele's example, $f(x) = \Gamma(x)$ on $(0, \infty)$. You can not take $\log$ two times since $\log \Gamma(x) < 0$ for some $x$ in $(0, \infty)$, right? In your question, do you mean: let $N$ be the greatest positive integer such that after $N$ log, the resulting function is less than or equal to zero for some $x$ in its domain?

Comment: @RiverLi I said "on its domain".... For any N, as long as the domain $I_N$ of log...log f(x) is such that log...log f(x) is convex, that is good. I don't care about the places where log...log f(x) is undefined.

Comment: Pick some $x$ known to be in the domain of $g_n(x) = \mathsf{log}^{\circ n} f(x)$ (the $n$-fold composition), $g_n(x)$ should be strictly convex.  But, it may be that $x$ is not in the domain of $g_{n + 1}$.  Perhaps something like $^{[x]}x$?  i.e. if $[x] = n$ is the integer part of x, $^nx$ is the $n$ tetration of $x$.

Comment: @NoOne  OK. Again Raffaele's example, how about $f(x) = \Gamma(x)$ on $(1,2)$, $\log \Gamma(x) < 0$ for all $x$ in $(1,2)$?

Comment: Presumably you also want $f$ itself to be strictly convex (else take $f \equiv 0$).

Comment: @Unit well yes. A function with empty domain (log 0) is convex by pure logic?

Comment: I meant a tower of Gamma, actually...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After realizing the flaw in my previous, affirmative, answer: No such function exists.

If $f$ has a nonempty domain at every point, then it grows arbitrarily large, but since it is continuous, after sufficiently many iterations of log its range will always be $(-\infty,\infty)$. WLOG, take $f$ to be such a function (if any valid $f$ exists, all of its logarithms are valid too). It is strictly monotonically increasing (as it is convex and not bounded below), so we let $c_0<c_1<c_2<\ldots$ be the unique points at which $f$ attains the values $0,1,e,e^e,e^{e^e},\ldots$.

Now consider $g=\log(f)$. We have $g(c_1)=0, g(c_2)=1$, and that $g$ is convex and monotonically increasing. We also have $\lim_{x\to c_0}g(x)=-\infty$. But then consider the line from $(x,g(x))$ to $(c_2,1)$; as $x$ approaches $c_0$ from the positive direction, this line will drop below the point $(c_1,0)$, violating convexity.

It is possible for $f$ and all logs applied to it to be convex on all positive values, as outlined in my other answer, but not over its whole domain.

Answer (score 0):

Define the function $g_n(x) = \text{exp}^{\circ n}(x - n)$ where by $\text{exp}^{\circ n}$ I mean the $n$-fold composition of the function.  So, $g_1(x) = \text{exp}(x - 1)$, $g_2(x) = \text{exp}(\text{exp}(x - 2))$ etc.

Then I think $f(x) = g_{[x]}(x)$ satisfies the desired property, where $[x]$ is the ceiling of $x$: suppose that $x$ is such that $[x] = n$, then $\text{log}^{\circ n} f(x) = x - n$ is convex.  Applying the $\text{log}$ again is not defined, so such an $x$ is only in the domain of $\text{log}^{\circ n}$ but not $\text{log}^{\circ (n + 1)}$.

EDIT: As mentioned in the comment, this has discontinuities at each integer.  A paper that develops the idea of $\text{exp}^{\circ x}$ can be found [here](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/10652460500422247).

Comment: Actually by "domain" I mean the whole domain of definition. I think your $f(x)$ is always convex "somewhere" (on some subinterval of its domain) on the domain of $\text{log}^{\circ n} f(x)$. But is it convex everywhere on its domain?

Comment: Yes actually there's a problem: there are discontinuities at each integer.  Possibly this idea can be extended in some way to $\text{exp}^{\circ x}(x)$?  Alternatively, I could take e.g. $f(x) = g_n(x)$ and restrict the domain so that $f(x) = \infty$ whenever $[x] \ne n$, although you do say *real* function, so I suppose something like this, or just $f(x) = \infty$ is not allowed.

Comment: @RJTK I get a University of Waterloo wall at your link. Do you have a freely available version?

Comment: Oops -- [this](http://eretrandre.org/rb/files/Hooshmand2006_83.pdf) appears to be a freely available copy.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: This function is only convex on its positive values, as pointed out in the comments. No such function exists - see my other answer.

A solution obtained via some modifications to RJTK's answer:

We set up our function so that it passes through $(0,0), (1/2,1), (3/4,e), (7/8,e^e),(15/16,e^{e^e}),$ and so on. Thus, after $n$ applications of log it will have a domain of $(1-2^{-n},1)$.

To interpolate between these points, we let $a_n=1-2^{-n}$ and define the function from $a_n$ to $a_{n+1}$ to be $\exp(\exp(\ldots\exp(g(\frac{x-a_n}{a_{n+1}-a_n})))$, where there are $n$ applications of the exponential and $g$ is a strictly convex increasing function on $[0,1]$ passing through $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$.

Since $\log(f(x)) = f(2x-1)$ for all $x$ such that this is defined, we need only check convexity of $f$ and the convexity of each application of log will follow.

Clearly, $f$ is continuous and strictly convex on $(a_n,a_{n+1})$. To see that it is convex at each $a_n$, we want to show that the slope at the start of the interval $(a_n,a_{n+1})$ exceeds that at the end of the interval $(a_{n-1},a_n)$. But $f$ has the property that $f'(x)=2f(x)\cdot f'(2x-1)$. So, by induction and the fact that $f$ is monotonically increasing, it suffices to check convexity at $x=\frac12$.

Here is where $g$ must be chosen; we need that $g'(1) \le 2g'(0)$, by the previous identity. Taking $g(x)=\frac{3x+x^2}{4}$ suffices for this.

(Originally, I tried defining $f(x)$ piecewise between integers, but this forced $g'(1) \le g'(0)$, i.e., that $g$ not be strictly convex. Allowing for the slope to double at each successive piece gets around this, albeit in a somewhat hacky way.)

Comment: On $(0, 1/2)$ the function is defined by $f(x) = e(3x+x^2)/4$. If you take the logarithm once, it is concave on (0.43, 0.5).

Comment: Ah, you’re right. I believe this is a typo, and the factor of e in the innermost parenthetical should be removed; I think this fixes things.

Comment: $\log f$ is actually concave on (0,0.5), both before and after removing $e$

Comment: So it is, I neglected the negative values attained by $f$. Oops. Edited this answer and posted a proof of impossibility.

Answer (score 0):

An interesting example is one defined by Hellmuth Kneser, as an analytic solution $E$ to Abel's equation which I see has been mentionned several times already:

> $\forall x>c,E(x+1)=\exp(E(x))$,

where $c$ is a real constant. The function is also strictly increasing and all of its derivatives are positive on (distinct) intervals $(b,+\infty)$, $b\geq c$. This is also the case for $\log \circ \cdot \cdot \cdot \log \circ E$ because of the functional equation above.

Comment: Why does it have an analytic solution? Or even a solution? It is also not clear why it is convex on its WHOLE domain

Comment: The existence of such solution is not trivial, it is the main result of Kneser's article (https://www.degruyter.com/view/book/9783110894516/10.1515/9783110894516.415.xml). The function is defined on a interval $(c,+\infty)$. Restricting to some $(c',+\infty)$ you can obtain that $E''>0$.

Comment: @NoOne Each function $\log \circ \cdot \cdot \cdot \circ \log \circ E$ won't be convex on the whole set of real numbers where it could possibly be defined, as per RavenclawPrefect's answer.